# not regular group homomorphism

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Let $G = GL(1,\mathbb{C})$, and let 
$\theta: G \rightarrow G$ defined by  $\theta(z) \mapsto \bar{z}$.

Show that $\theta$ is a group homomorphism that is not regular.

Perhaps my struggle comes from not understanding the definitions completely, but I have no clue as to how to solve this.
Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially $G=\Bbb C^\times$ and we want to show there is no polynomial $z$ such that $p(z)=\bar{z}$ for all nonzero complex numbers $z$. In particular, it suffices to show there is no polynomial for which it holds on the unit circle, where $\bar{z}=z^{-1}$. Is $p(z)=z^{-1}$ for all unit modulus $z$ possible?

Comment: $G$ is not the set of unit modulus complex numbers, it is the set of non-zero complex numbers.

Comment: Sorry, edited. ${}$